# How can I change value of checkbox in angular 8 on ionViewWillEnter()

Tags: html, angular, forms, checkbox, ionic4

Since I'm using ion-router my input fields i.e checkbox seems to keep its value since the component is not destroyed when I'm navigating through the same hierarchy. Whenever ngOnDestroy() is called and I go back to the view it works as required i.e checkbox value is set to default. So I need some way where I can grab the value from the input field and change it to default i.e false in ionViewWillEnter(), for cases when I'm in the same navigating hierarchy.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between border-bottom p-2">
 <label translate="Test"></label>
 <input class="align-middle" type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this problem is using @ViewChild() component from angular.

HTML code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between border-bottom p-2">
 <label translate="Test"></label>
 <input class="align-middle" type="checkbox" #checkBox1 />
</div>
```

Component code:

```
@ViewChild("checkBox1", { static: false }) checkBox1: ElementRef;

public ionViewWillEnter() {
 this.checkBox1.nativeElement.checked = false;
}
```

So every time the view will enter using ViewChild() we can set the checked value of the element to false.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't using any Angular / Ionic features for your inputs.

What I would expect to see is either an `[ngModel]` or the `value` being set.

You can do it like this:

// markup

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between border-bottom p-2">
 <label translate="Test"></label>
 <input class="align-middle" type="checkbox" [ngModel]="yourInputNameHere" />
</div>
```

Then if you had a variable on the backend:

```
let yourInputNameHere: boolean = false;
```

And that can be used to set the value in `ionViewWillEnter()`.

Comment: I've tried using [ngModel] as you said but it still won't make a difference. I tried with normal variable as well as Observable and Behaviour Subject but non seems to solve my issue. The reason being when the component is initialised, the ngModel value is passed to it and it sets the value, when the user clicks it to either check or uncheck it keeps that value. Since component is not re-rendered it keeps the last value and does not update on ionViewWillEnter().
This checkbox is used in ngx bootstrap model, if there is a way i can destroy the modal that can work as well.